# Change color of points according to a variable in qplot in R

Tags: r

I have the following code snippet. When I am plotting the first graph I am getting color of plotted points as a color gradient. However when I am plotting the second graph, I am getting distinct colors for the plotted points. I want to have similar colors for the plotted points in graph 1 as in graph 2. Please help.

```
area<-c(1:21)
time<-c('11','11','11','11','11','00','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11')
freq<-c(10,12,3,5,8,15,20,16,30,34,50,40,45,35,31,21,27,17,19,11,49)
time2<-c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11')
df<-data.frame(area,time,time2,freq)

qplot(x=time,y=freq,data = df,geom = 'point',
  color = area,xlab="Hours of the Day",
  ylab="Maximum Frequency of Crimes in Area",
  main = "Affected Areas according to time of Occurrence")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,50),breaks = seq(0,50,2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

qplot(x=time,y=freq,data = df,geom = 'point',
  color = time2,xlab="Hours of the Day",
  ylab="Maximum Frequency of Crimes in Area",
  main = "Affected Areas according to time of Occurrence")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,50),breaks = seq(0,50,2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Thank you.

Comment: area is a continuous variable whereas time2 is a discrete variable. If you want the color gradient in both graphics, you want to convert time2 to a continuous variable (numeric variable).

Comment: I want to have different colors for the plotted points of the continuous variable as in the discrete variable.

Comment: Does that mean you want to have color gradient with 11 colors for a continuous variable given the second graphic has 11 colors?

Comment: I want to have 21 unique colors for the continuous variable area similar to the second graphic; but 21 colors and not 11.

Comment: I personally think that is a large number of color, and I am not sure if people can identify all colors. In addition, you would have gradient for each color, right? If I were you, I would not produce such a graphic.

Comment: I don't want any gradient. I just want 21 unique colors similar to the second graphic. Also, please suggest what else would you have done with such data.

Comment: How can you have 21 unique colors if there are only 11 unique values?

Comment: The variable area has 21 unique values but is continuous in nature. I want 21 unique colors for each value of the area column and plot a graph similar to graphic 2; but with 21 values having distinct colors instead of 11.

Comment: Then, why don't you convert area to factor?

Comment: It worked. Thank you.